# What is the name for the specific character archetype common in traditional Sword and Planet stories like John Carter?

Tags: terminology

You see it a lot more in other ERB works like *Pellucidar* or Philip José Farmer's *World of Tiers* (John Carter is just the most famous these days). It's a term used to describe the standard character from this era of fantasy books who exemplifies the best of all areas of modern society. I learned the term a while back while reading some sort of literary analysis (maybe even Wikipedia, in fact I think there was even a page about it) but now can't find again and it's been on the tip of my mind for days. It's along the lines of "übermensch" but it's not that - it's two other words that mean basically the same thing.

Basically, this character exhibits the best qualities of everyone in modern society mixed into one man who can then succeed against the savages of the world he's transported to (for some of the seminal authors like Burroughs and Haggard this was a blatantly racist attempt to highlight how civilized Europeans were better than "savage native" societies, but that's outside the scope of my question).

The protagonist is typically introduced as just a normal, modern man (albeit a particularly strong and brave one), but turns out to in fact be a Renaissance-esque paragon of every virtue of his society. He's not just the consummate hero ready to throw himself into danger to save the day, he's also an expert in history, languages, science, the humanities, modern physical combat, medicine, and ancient weaponry for some reason. He understands chemistry and physics enough to recreate modern inventions in the pre-industrial world he's transported to, he learned horsemanship, swordplay, and/or archery as hobbies despite coming from a gunpowder-era world, he was a university champion boxer who can use modern techniques to defeat the muscular savages he now faces, he may have a classical education in ancient languages sufficient to communicate with the natives of his new world, he understands psychology, sociology, and/or political science enough to organize his allies into a modern army and to manipulate his opponents . . .

Anyway, the actual literary analysis I read describes this a lot better and my brain will itch until I can remember the term for it.

Comment: There's a lot of words to describe a ["perfect" hero](https://www.jsmorin.com/2013/02/7-types-of-heroes/#:~:text=The%20Perfect%20Hero,feel%20inspired%20or%20perhaps%20inferior.). Personally, I'd go for '*paragon*', but that's purely my own opinion.

Comment: Or polymath, maybe.

Comment: That's true, but I'm asking if anyone is familiar with the particular term that's used in analysis of this specific genre, not asking people to come up with a term that would work. Like the terms "lost world" or "Mary Sue" or "hero's journey" all describe ideas that could be explained in any number of ways, but those are particular, set terms people have come up with and defined in certain contexts. There's a particular term I've seen used to talk about this John Carter/David Innes/ (particularly discussions of ERB's works) and I'm totally blanking on it.

Comment: The "Renaissance man," maybe? I see that you already mention the Renaissance.

Comment: This isn't really about science fiction or fantasy though

Comment: Are you seeking a flattering name or not?

Comment: If I were you, I would flag this for migration to [Writing.SE]. This should be on-topic over there

Comment: [Competent man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competent_man) perhaps?